# Multiple IP address lookup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ip, ip-geolocation

I was wondering if there is an API that will allow me to insert a 100 or more IP addresses separated by a new line, trace them retrieve their info all in one push of a button? At the moment I am using a free API but I cannot figure out if it can trace multiple IP addresses and if so, how?

Here is the API url: http://www.ipaddressapi.com/

and here is the url where I enter the IP address at the end of it:

http://www.ipaddressapi.com/l/55ffa3e1bb4f123a2e0e21bf30a6731fec615a69b682?h=45.0.0.0

I tried doing it like this

http://www.ipaddressapi.com/l/55ffa3e1bb4f123a2e0e21bf30a6731fec615a69b682?h=45.0.0.0&47.0.0.0 (Adding & then the second IP address) but that didn't work either. Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Purchase an API license and/or database.

Comment: Just do the lookup in a loop?

Comment: @MattWilko Thinking of it, I might be able to read a file which has those addresses and then through a loop, lookup all of them. Any Idea on how the loop would be achieved ? I have written the code for reading the file which has Ip addresses separated by a new line. The loop will read each IP address alone, and add it as an argument to the link mentioned above triggered by a click of a button. Then the results would be displayed on a label for example. Any thoughts about such a loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like the following:

Loop through your ip addresses:

```
For Each s as String in MyAddresses
    'Add the ip address on the end of the url you wish to get the data for:
    Dim result as string = GetWebPageAsString(New Uri("http://someaddress.com?" + s))
    'parse result however you need to here
Next
```

A function to get web page as a string

```
Public Shared Function GetWebPageString(ByVal address As Uri) As String
    Try
        Using client As New Net.WebClient()
            Return client.DownloadString(address)
        End Using
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```